# Install ZombieDriver for Mink/Behat under Windows

Tags: behat, mink, zombie.js

The installation instructions at http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/drivers/zombie.html are (a) incomplete and (b) Linux only.

How can I install ZombieDriver on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

1. Follow the instructions at http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/drivers/zombie.html and just skip this step: `export NODE_PATH="/PATH/TO/NPM/node_modules"`
2. Set up your `behat.yml` like this:

   ```
   default:
       # ...
       extensions:
           Behat\MinkExtension:
               base_url: http://www.example.com/
               default_session: zombie
               javascript_session: zombie
               zombie: 
                 node_modules_path: 'C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules'
   ```

However, I'm not sure if this is the "right" or recommended way, but it works for me. I'm just posting this here cause I couldn't find any other resource on the web.